# Bootstrap dropdown option not showing after selected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following form, that when the dropdown is clicked and an option selected, the option doesn't appear at the top:

```
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">+1 <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#" id="1">US: +1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="44">UK: +44</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="Your   
   phone number"> <span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">SUBMIT</button>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
   // Load dialog on page load
   $('#basic-modal-content').modal();

   // Load dialog on click
   $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
   $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
   return false;
   });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/vc1g3kyg/4/)

Comment: If I understand good you want to have the selected value as default shown in the dropdown button? If the case by default won't work instead use select option or  a ready made plugin for bootstrap

Comment: Your code sample and your question don't seem to correspond. What does a modal have to do with the question? Where do you expect the option to show? (A Bootstrap dropdown isn't a select box.)

Comment: Just pay attention to the jsfiddle. The point is that if you select an option from the dropdown, it doesn't show as the default. So if you select "UK: +44", it doesn't show as the selected option.

Comment: The question is, why are you using a bootstrap dropdown and not a select?  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ncxkz3rz/

Comment: @PatrickLC, because that's not how the input was designed.

Comment: @PatrickLC Read the documentation in Bootstrap on Button/Input groups. Asker has the correct and valid functionality.

Comment: Matt: ok. @TimLewis: I am not saying that this is invalid. I'm just saying that if the asker is using a form, then for this functionality the easy way is to use a select control, as stated in http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls

Comment: @PatrickLC I understand, it's all good. I think there was some confusion/disagreement over functionality vs display :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Bootply that changes the button `html` attribute when you choose a new one.

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/hL3VNRU1BM)

And the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="label" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">+1 <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#" id="1">US: +1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="44">UK: +44</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="Your   
phone number" type="text"> <span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">SUBMIT</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#1, #44").click(function(e){
  $("#label").html("+" + $(this).attr("id") + " <span class='caret'></span>");
});
```

As per the comments, I really don't know what the second part of your question's code is all about, but changing the value of a button based on something you click is pretty simple. Note, I added an `id="label"` to the button to make accessing and changing it easier.

Hope that helps!